# ConfigureAwait(false) not needed in Console/Win service apps, right?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have been using `async`/`await` for a while, but delved deeper recently, and read a lot of best practice tips saying to by default always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent deadlocks and improve performance.

I just want to make sure I am not missing something when I presume this only applies when the is an actual current `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler` in play, correct?

If I have a Windows service app that is responding to messages/commands/etc. asynchronously, it always just uses the default scheduler = probably the same threadpool thread that the awaitable completed on will execute the continuation, thus no deadlock and no performance difference can be had from using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, correct?

It's not like I can't put it there, but I hate noisey code so much...

Comment: Preferably you should write code that is modular and does not care if it is running in a console, a windows service, a ASP.NET site, or a windowed project (so yes, you should put it in because your code could be run in a situations where it would need it), but sometimes you know it won't be used in those situations (so no, you should not put it in). Its a matter of coding style.

Comment: It should actually never be used! At most it is just a hack (that clutters your code). Don't use the Wait() method and you will be fine.

Comment: (and .Result aswell)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, this is true.  When working in a Console or Service scenario, there is no `SynchronizationContext` installed (*by default*) so the `continueOnCapturedContext` option in `ConfigureAwait` will have no effect, which means you can safely remove it without changing the runtime behavior.

However, there can be exceptions, so I would often suggest writing your code including `ConfigureAwait(false)` when appropriate anyways.

The main advantages of including this even in a console or service application are:

1. The code becomes reusable in other applications later.  If you choose to reuse this code, you won't have to track down bugs that arise from not including this.
2. If you happen to install (or use a library that installs) a `SynchronizationContext` while running, the behavior of your methods won't change.

Comment: In my opinion you should never use this as it is at best just a hack and clutters your code significantly. "Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack)" https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @maracuja-juice  -- you misunderstood the author of that article (Stephen Cleary).  What he meant was don't use ConfigureAwait(false) for the sole purpose of avoiding deadlocks in code that blocks.  Instead, don't block; avoid deadlocks by using async/await all the way up and down the call stack, including at the root.

Comment: That's exactly what I understood @rory.ap

Comment: So then your statement "in my opinion you should never use this" is misleading and doesn't represent what you claim you understood about his article.