# Why would DeviceClient SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync timeout immediately after OpenAsync succeeded?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

As part of my initialization of an IoTHub DeviceClient I explicitly open the connection with OpenAsync and then immediately call SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync. Sometimes when I call SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync it times out with an exception. If my network connection is stable, why don't I get the timeout on OpenAsync instead of SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync? I believe it even makes the same OpenAsync call internally to ensure the connection is open.

```
ioTHubModuleClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, settings);
await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await ioTHubModuleClient.SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync(OnModulePropertyUpdateRequested, this).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Update:**
I found that if I register with SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler before that, I can see that its endlessly connecting/disconnecting until it times out when I call SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync.

> IoTHub connection is now Connected Reason: Connection_Ok 
>   IoTHub connection is now Disconnected_Retrying Reason: No_Network 
>   IoTHub connection is now Connected Reason: Connection_Ok 
>   IoTHub connection is now Disconnected_Retrying Reason: No_Network 
>   IoTHub connection is now Connected Reason: Connection_Ok 
>   IoTHub connection is now Disconnected_Retrying Reason: No_Network

I used dotPeek to decompile the Microsoft.Azure.Devices stuff and serve it up through a local pdb server. What seems to be happening is that something is generating a SocketException for a successful operation. The exception messages is "The operation completed successfully". This blog indicates this is typically due to a dllimport call not using [SetLastError](https://www.medo64.com/2013/03/error-the-operation-completed-successfully/). I don't see anything in the callstack that obviously leads to a pinvoke call though:

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Mqtt.MqttIotHubAdapter.d__40.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Mqtt.MqttIotHubAdapter.d__28.MoveNext()

Comment: Is the code you provided executed in a Console Application or an UI Application? @Tim Bertalot

Comment: Console application.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, when working in a Console App or Service scenario, there is no SynchronizationContext installed (by default), so the continueOnCapturedContext option in ConfigureAwait will have no effect.However if you happen to install or use a library that installs a *SynchronizationContext*, the behavior of the async methods will be like in UI application. *ConfigureAwait(false)* will change the context.An important rule is that each async method has its own context,it means that the calling method is not affected by *ConfigureAwait*. You can refer to these topics to get good know details about *Task.ConfigureAwait*.

- [ConfigureAwait(false) not needed in Console/Win service apps, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817703/configureawaitfalse-not-needed-in-console-win-service-apps-right)
- [Why would I bother to use Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851073/why-would-i-bother-to-use-task-configureawaitcontinueoncapturedcontext-false)